# C-M-l locks the screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

[Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html) says that `C-M-l` is to Scroll heuristically to bring useful information onto the screen (`reposition-window`).

When I type `C-M-l` in Ubuntu, Emacs 27.1, the OS is automatically locking the screen.

Which alternative keybinding could I use to call the `reposition-window` command?

Comment: I don't think this is related to Emacs. Provided you are using Ubuntu with GNOME, you could use `Keyboard Shortcuts` to change the lock screen key binding to something else and free it for Emacs.

Comment: Your DE is intercepting that key chord - emacs never sees it. So you need to modify the settings of your DE.

Comment: @NickD: I think he knows that it's caught by his OS, but he's asking what that key sequence would do if it weren't caught by the OS and how to access it given that he can't use `C-M-l`, so it looks on-topic to me.

Comment: You almost answered your own question by quoting the documentation: as it says, the command normally called by `C-M-l` is `reposition-window`, and therefore you can use `M-x reposition-window` to call it.  You can also ask Emacs which keys are bound to that command with either `C-h w reposition-window` or `C-h f reposition-window`.  By default no other keys are bound; but of course you can add your own custom keybindings for any command.

Comment: n.b. If you use Emacs a lot, you probably *will* want to disable a lot of your window manager's key bindings -- they often interfere a lot.  I recommend disabling anything you don't care about, and changing anything which you do want to use that conflicts with something useful in Emacs (or certainly with things in Emacs that you have pre-existing muscle-memory for).

Comment: @phils: Indeed, the latest change almost includes the answer in the question.  The only missing detail, I think is to point out that you can replace the `M-` modifier with the `ESC` prefix key, so you can type `ESC C-l` to run whichever command is bound to `M-C-l`.

Comment: I know that `M-x reposition-window` will do the work. But, since this thing happened suddenly (I checked it twice), I thought of asking in the  forum.

Answer (score 1):

I accept the coments of @phils and @Stefan.

We have to use `ESC`,if we are finding problem combination `C-M-*`.